# Looping over items from a list Emacs

Tags: list, function, emacs

Let's say we have a list like the following:

`("These" "Are "Some" "Words")`, let us call it `listy`

How to call a function on each of those items of the list?

Perhaps call a function like:

```
(defun messager (somelist) 
 (interactive)
 (message somelist)
)
```

Running the function:

`(messager listy)`

I would expect in the buffer to see seperate lines for each item of the list.

The part that is not working though, is to loop or something over the items from the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
(mapc 'messager listy)
```

or

```
(dolist (item listy)
  (messager item))
```

Comment: I guess you meant `(messager item)` in the second example.

Comment: I got `dolist` to work. Is there something for an `alist` as well?

Comment: `alist` is a list. So, `(dolist (pair alist) ...do something with (car pair) and (cdr pair)...)`

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm going for self-advertising once again :P But in hopes that I will communicate some useful info on the way:

```lisp
;; Here is what `dolist' expands to:
(dolist (item listy)
  (messager item))

(identity
 (catch (quote --cl-block-nil--)
   (let ((--dolist-tail-- listy) item)
     (while --dolist-tail--
       (setq item (car --dolist-tail--))
       (messager item)
       (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))))

;; And here is what `i-iterate' expands to:
(++ (for item in listy)
      (messager item))

(let* ((--0 listy) item)
  (while --0
    (setq item (car --0) --0 (cdr --0))
    (messager item)))
```

Some commentary: `dolist` will create a `(catch ...)` block whether there or not there is a conditional exit, while `i-iterate` will try to do that only if such conditional exit was identified. Generally, executing code inside `(catch ...)` form is a little slower.

Also, `dolist` will wrap the code into a special "block" (which is basically just the call to `identity` function. This is, too, a sort of cruft, that is a default, but not always needed.

Now, to your other question about `alist`, you could use `loop` macro like so:

```lisp
(loop for (key . value) in '((a . b) (c . d)) do
      (message "key: %s -> value: %s" key value))
;; Which expands to:
(identity
 (catch (quote --cl-block-nil--)
   (let* ((--cl-var-- (quote ((a . b) (c . d)))) (value nil) (key nil))
     (while (consp --cl-var--)
       (setq value (car --cl-var--) 
             key (car (prog1 value (setq value (cdr value)))))
       (message "key: %s -> value: %s" key value)
       (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil)))

;; Compared to i-iterate
(++ (for (key . value) in '((a . b) (c . d)))
  (message "key: %s -> value: %s" key value))
;; Which expands to:
(let* ((--0 (quote ((a . b) (c . d)))) value key)
  (while --0
    (setq key (caar --0) value (cdar --0) --0 (cdr --0))
    (message "key: %s -> value: %s" key value)))
```

Where, in this particular case using `pop` was not justified. Likewise the use of `(catch ...)` block (since there wasn't a conditional exit).

Oh, and the link to the library: http://code.google.com/p/i-iterate/ :)

---

The benefits and downsides of using `mapc` for this purpose: The high-order functions combine well with already existing functions. So, if you already had one you wanted to apply to every element - that would be, probably, the best way to solve your problem. However, if you are going to create a function only to use it with a high-order function - then it rarely pays off, as you will create a "redundant" instance, which you could've otherwise avoided. It is not always the case, and some times, especially when used with macros, this can be a powerful tool, but as is your case, the iteration seems to be better suited.